# Hidden fields are not posted if the page gets submitted using "a href"?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
$sort=$_REQUEST['sortby']; 
 echo" $sort ";  
?>  
<html>
<head>  
</head>
    <body>  
<form method="get" id="thisForm" >  
          <table border=1>  
        <tr>  
            <td>  
                <a href="" name="say" onclick="javascript: sorting(0)">Day </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="" name="server" onclick="javascript: sorting(1)">Server </a>  
            </td>  
            <td>  
                <a href="" name="service" onclick="javascript: sorting(2)">Service </a>  
            </td>  
            <td>  
                <a href="" name="count" onclick="javascript: sorting(3)">Count </a>  
            </td>  
        </tr>  
    </table>    
        <input type="hidden" name="sortby"  id="sortby"/>  
    </form>  
    </body>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" >  

var sortArray=new Array("say","server","service","count");  
function sorting( cnt)  
{  
    alert(sortArray[cnt]);  
    document.getElementById("sortby").value=sortArray[cnt];  
}
```

Based on the Header clicked i am trying to build a sort query but after it is submitted on clicking the "a href" link i am unable to get the hidden field posted data ?

I have changed "a href" to submit buttons then how do you stop the page being submitted if we click the same "sort by" link.

Comment: a don't post any form..... use input button

Comment: maybe add `document.getElementById("thisForm").submit` to js code?

Comment: There's no such thing as "submission using an href" blockquote.

Comment: Also no need for the `javascript:` bit, but return false in mandatory

Comment: I have used submit buttons instead of "a href", but how do you prevent a button from submitting the page if it was sorted by the same field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you're missing:

- A link does not submit the form with input data, it just changes the url.
- Submit the form.
- Override the default `<a>` behavior (for example, using `return false`).

An updated version of `sorting`:

```
var sortArray=new Array("say","server","service","count");  
function sorting(cnt)  
{  
    document.getElementById("sortby").value = sortArray[cnt];  
    document.getElementById("thisForm").submit();
    return false;
}
```

You can call it using:

```
<a href="" name="say" onclick="return sorting(0);">Day </a>
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/ukoton/3

Another option is to use the popular library jQuery, which can greatly simplify your code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#thisForm a').click(function(ev){
    var sortValue = this.name;
    // an alternative to this.name is to use a data-sortBy='day' attribute, 
    // and then $(this).data('sortBy')
    $('#sortby').val(sortValue);
    $('#thisForm').submit();
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/ukoton/4

Comment: no need to return false after submitting the form, as you should have already left the page.

Comment: Just don't use a link for posting a form. That's what the submit button is for. You can style it to look like a link if you want too, but using an actual link will make the form unusable for people without javascript. That might include people using accessibility tools.

Answer (score 1):

By default, anchor tags (that being A) do not submit a form. You can either use a button or submit the form using javascript.

You can submit the form from javascript with `document.thisForm.submit()`

Comment: in some browsers that would only work if the form had NAME="thisForm" so `document.getElementById('thisForm').submit()` is likely a better choice

Answer (score 0):

Hmm .. I am not a php guy .. so I guess that initial 4 lines tries to get the sortby field from the form, anyways href link is not equivalent to html form submit, you will need to explicitly submit the form, maybe using javascript, to get the value

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Submit button and style it to look like a link, if you need to. Using Javascript shouldn't be needed here.

Using an actual link instead of a Submit button will make the form unusable for people without javascript. That might include people using accessibility tools. Apart from that, it makes your page more complex (adding illogical HTML, and requiring Javascript), and therefore more complex to maintain.

Comment: MrGlass already suggested that 7 months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8890439/7586 . As for "illogical HTML", the question is a mess, but we work with what we've got.